# Is it possible to spy on Tor browser within local network?

Tags: network, tor, onion-routing

Imagine yourself connecting your personal device to your workplace wi-fi network.

Can managers, network administrators, or some other person/potential attacker see my browser's activity if I'm using Tor browser or run all my traffic through the Tor network?

Comment: Are you using their computer? If yes, then yes. If no, then they can at least tell if you're using Tor on their network.

Comment: @user Edited my question to be more readable for the reader. 
I'm referring to situation where you are connected to that local network.

Comment: Always assume that anything you do on a company computer is fully monitored by the company.  Because as a general rule of thumb, if they want to, they can.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This answer is based on the assumption that the adversary is able to monitor the traffic to/from your device, but has not compromised your device.

In that case, the adversary may be able to see that you are using Tor, because they'll see connections from your device to nodes on the Tor network.  But, that person won't be able to determine which sites on the Tor network you or visiting, and won't be able to see the information that you are exchanging with those sites.

See https://www.csoonline.com/article/3287653/what-is-the-tor-browser-how-it-works-and-how-it-can-help-you-protect-your-identity-online.html for more info.

Answer (score 0):

No, that would defeat the purpose of Tor.

If it is truly your personal device and is not running any work software, and if the Tor Browser and network behave as designed and you are following [best practices](https://tb-manual.torproject.org/), then other parties on the network will not be able see your activities over Tor.

Comment: Could you elaborate on "following best practices"?

Comment: @I.Raleigh sort of a catch all, covering everything from verifying the Tor executable(s) to ensuring your traffic is actually making it through Tor if not using the browser.  Basically, following their docs is sufficient.